# Is it possible to create a custom GTest TEST macro for AOSP codebase?

Tags: c++, android-source, googletest

Is it possible to create a custom Test macro or wrapper that wraps one of the GTest test macros (TEST, TEST_F, TEST_P, etc) and adds some custom functionality?

The codebase I'm working with is in AOSP and already has a custom macro that is defined like so:

```
#define CUSTOM_TEST_F(fixture, test_name, metadata) TEST_F(fixture, test_name##_metadata_##metadata)
```

Instead of modifying the test name with the metadata, I would like to change it so that the metadata is handled elsewhere (before, during, or after the actual test body), something like below, where the `CUSTOM_TEST_F` implementation does the same/similar thing as the `TEST_F` implementation:

```
class MyCustomTest : public ::testing::Test {
    void SetUp() override {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

CUSTOM_TEST_F(MyCustomTest, test_name, metadata) {
    <test_body>
}

TEST_F(MyCustomTest, test_name) {
    <test_body>
    std::cout << metadata << std::endl;
}
```

As for why I am not simply overriding SetUp/TearDown or the base Test class, the codebase has several thousand tests divided across hundreds of test classes, I think it would be easiest for me to modify the macro directly or change it into a wrapper of sorts if possible.

Looking at the GTest documentation, I saw that a custom EventListener might be a good way to go, but I'm not sure how to register it for an AOSP build (still a bit of an Android noob).